# Flex 3 ComboBox skin, limiting text width

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, combobox, skinning

I've created a ComboBox skin by extending mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin. It's working fine, except I can't figure out how to limit the width of the text. Is there a way to control this within the skin?

See the attached image for an example of the text going too far. I would like it to stop before the separator line to the left of the down arrow.

[image: Text going too far in ComboBox]

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the width of the label according to the control width.

Comment: Thanks! How do I set the width of the ComboBox label from within the ProgrammaticSkin, though?

Comment: Try to override the updateDisplayList(width:Number, height:Number):void method